# Query optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

```
SELECT nar.name, nar.reg, stat.lvl
FROM members AS nar
JOIN stats AS stat 
ON stat.id = nar.id
WHERE nar.ref = 9
```

I have indexes on id in both tables and I have index referavo either. But still, it checks all rows in stats table (I use Explain to get this information), but in members table it checks only one row how it supposed to be. What's wrong with stats table? Thank you very much.

```
CREATE TABLE `members` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL
 `ref` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT


CREATE TABLE `stats` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=37 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC



id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows Extra
1 SIMPLE stat ALL PRIMARY NULL NULL NULL 22  
1 SIMPLE nar eq_ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 4 table_nme.stat.id 1 Using where
```

Comment: Please post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE members`, `SHOW CREATE TABLE stats` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

Comment: ok, give me a second. thanks.

Comment: Do `stat.id` and `nar.id` have the same data types?

Comment: I guess you have mysql < 5.1? Try an upgrade to 5.1, the index management is better. `SELECT @@version;`

Comment: Yes, Lukas, it has the same data types.

Comment: @ring0: Server version: 5.1.33-community

Comment: @Mark Byers: I've done that, but I deleted other unnecessary data

Comment: @hey: Please don't modify the output - that risks introducing errors or removing vital information that you didn't realize was relevant. Modify your tables instead to remove the unneeded columns, verify that you still get the same behaviour, then post the SHOW and EXPLAIN outputs **in full** and **unmodified** for these new tables. Create a backup first of course, or else do this in a new schema so that you don't break your existing database.

Comment: @Mark Byers: posted the explain output. Ok, I will try to edit table and don't modify it. But if you see an error now, please let me know.

Comment: @hey: Can you also please post `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM members` and `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stats`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your tables are ridiculously small - just 23 rows is **tiny**.

MySQL chooses different query plans depending on how many rows there are in the table and based on how many it estimates will be selected (from the statistics). You should performance test your queries with *realistic data* - both the amount of data and the distribution of values in the data should be as realistic as possible. Otherwise the query plan MySQL chooses in testing might not be the same the actual query plan for your live system.

Your tables are so small that using an index could be **slower** than just checking the table directly. Remember that checking data that is already in memory is fast, but reads are slow. Accessing an index can require an extra read - first the index has to be fetched and read to find which rows to select, then if your index isn't a covering index the relevant rows in the table have to be fetched and read to get the values that aren't in the index. MySQL is perfectly entitled to not use an index even if one is available if it believes that doing so will result in a slower plan.

Put some more rows in your table (thousands) and try running EXPLAIN again. You will probably find that when you have more rows that the PRIMARY KEY index will be used for the join.

Comment: now it has only 23 rows, but in the future it will have hundreds or even thousands of rows.

Comment: @hey: By the way, that's one of the reasons why I was asking you to post the complete and unmodified output of SHOW CREATE TABLE. Such an error would have been spotted immediately if you had posted this output in the question.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL can use only one index at a time per table, thus it sees the `member` row using the index, and then performs a sequential search for the ID.

You have to create a multi columns index for the `members` table

```
 CREATE INDEX idref ON members(id,ref);
```

please try the reverse one as well if it doesn't get better (first: drop index idref on members)

```
 CREATE INDEX idref ON members(ref,id);
```

(I cannot try it myself now)

Comment: Is it true that MySQL can use only one index at a time per table? That mean that I can do nothing about it.

Comment: You can add a multi column index for the relevant tables.

Comment: @ring0: Yeah, now it works. But I am guessing that it is not efficient to add one more index just for one query which happens a few times an hour, right?

Comment: It depends on the number of rows you have. If your tables grow a lot and MySQL has to perform a sequential search on a lot of rows, an index is worth the performance gain. The index size is also proportional to the size of the table. If the query is to be used *temporarily* for a few months, the index on a small table is not necessary. But if you plan a long term use - I would create the correct index. Depends on if you are the only user/developer/maintainer... If not, it is better to create a DB model that copes with scalability.

Comment: @hey This is not for the 15 reps, but I think my answer matches your question, no?

Comment: @ring0: It appears that it works with more than only one index. I just didn't put it on ref.

Comment: @hey It works with more than one index... But using only one index *per table*. This is why a multi-columns index has to be created for queries that involve several columns from the *same* table. There are many articles about this, for instance http://www.martynov.org/2007/08/4-silly-mistakes-in-use-of-mysql.html